# Element not excluded in dependencyManagement of parent, failure of OWASP-check

Tags: java, spring, maven, owasp, cve

I have a project which contains, in its configuration POM, a BOM-reference in the dependencyManagement section. The normal build lifecycle stages run perfectly fine. When I am doing an OWASP-security analysis (*mvn org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:check*), the dependency  jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar: fails with *CVE-2022-31569*.

When checking out the dependency-tree, this dependency is a transitive dependency of a transitive dependency (*spring-boot-starter*) of *spring-boot-starter-web*.

I have tried to exclude jakarta-annotation in the configuration-pom, yet this does not change the dependency-tree at all - the dependency persists as if I had done nothing. Below the configuration-pom:

```
<groupId>nl.loxia.beheer</groupId>
<artifactId>engineeringsruimte-service.configuratie</artifactId>
<version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>configuratie</name>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>nl.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycompany-spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <maven.deploy.skip>false</maven.deploy.skip>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Own artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.mycompany.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-service.domain</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.mycompany.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-service.external</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.mycompany.project</groupId>
            <artifactIdmyproject-service.control</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.myproject.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>myproject-service.web</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Company -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>mycompany-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.7</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

       <!--- other deps -->

</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Testing -->
    <!-- more deps -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <suppressionFiles>
                        <suppressionFile>owasp-suppression.xml</suppressionFile>
                    </suppressionFiles>
                    <skipSystemScope>true</skipSystemScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

It fails during the owasp-check of the myproject-service.web-module, which uses  spring-boot-starter-web, and through it, jakarta.annotation-api.

Does anyone know why this dependency is not excluded? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/jeremylong/DependencyCheck/issues/4671 - you either need to update `dependency-check-maven` - it has own built-it suppression list, or modify your suppression list.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's a parent pom, it could be that `jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar` is a transitive dependency of the parent project